# Assigning multiple shorthand conditional statements in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I have container that gives it a class of **dark** if the length is greater then 0.

```
<div ng-class="{dark: name.length > 0}">Hi</div>
```

Is there a way to add another condition to this? So maybe if not, give it a class of **white**. Or an entirely different conditional statement to give it a class of **white**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
<div ng-class="{'dark': name.length > 0, 'white': name.length <= 0}">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the multiple conditional statement. Didn't know I could use a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can Angular's ternary operator

```
<div ng-class="(name.length > 0) ? 'dark' : 'white'">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (ternary) if it's based on the same condition

```
<div ng-class="name.length ? 'white' : 'dark'">Hi</div>
```

If you want different conditions to each class you could do

```
<div ng-class="{'dark': name.length > 0, 'white': name.length == 5}">Hi</div>
```

I've used `name.length == 5` as an example for `white` class

Comment: Thank you for showing multiple but your missing a bracket on the lats example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, you could add as many conditions as you want for a class:

```
 <div ng-class="{'dark': name.length > 0 || name.length !> 10 , 'light': name.length < 0}">Hi</div>
```